# The difference between Redux-Logic and Redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

What are the advantages of using redux-logic that could be acheived rather than using redux-thunk?

Comment: As far as I can see `redux-logic` also does action interceptions. `redux-thunk` is a simple async action creator. You should examine both libraries and decide to use the proper one according to your needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Redux-thunk is very simple (about 10 lines of code) middleware which allows to [dispatch functions](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#motivation). That is all it do.

   When dispatching function you can do some other work (inside this function), like fetching data or something else before/after dispatching action (action - means object which will go directly to reducer).
2. Redux-logic is much more flexible and powerful middleware. It allows to [express your intention](https://github.com/jeffbski/redux-logic#tldr) when writing code.

This sample taken from documentation

```
const fetchPollsLogic = createLogic({

  // declarative built-in functionality wraps your code
  type: FETCH_POLLS, // only apply this logic to this type
  cancelType: CANCEL_FETCH_POLLS, // cancel on this type
  latest: true, // only take latest

  // your code here, hook into one or more of these execution
  // phases: validate, transform, and/or process
  process({ getState, action }, dispatch, done) {
      axios.get('https://survey.codewinds.com/polls')
          .then(resp => resp.data.polls)
          .then(polls => dispatch({ type: FETCH_POLLS_SUCCESS,
                            payload: polls }))
          .catch(err => {
              console.error(err); // log since could be render err
              dispatch({ type: FETCH_POLLS_FAILED, payload: err,
                    error: true })
       })
       .then(() => done()); // call done when finished dispatching
    }
});
```

This sample is fetching data, but it intention and stages (in this case it has only one stage, process) is clear from code.

Doing the same using Redux-thunk will lead to such code

```
const fetchPollsLogic = () => (dispatch) => {
    axios.get('https://survey.codewinds.com/polls')
       .then(resp => resp.data.polls)
       .then(polls => dispatch({ type: FETCH_POLLS_SUCCESS,
                            payload: polls }))
       .catch(err => {
           console.error(err); // log since could be render err
           dispatch({ type: FETCH_POLLS_FAILED, payload: err,
                 error: true })
        })
 }
```

The code is essentially the same, but lacks of declarative style, division into stages and so on.

I may recommend to read thru redux-logic, as it much more powerful and flexible compared to redux-thunk